# How to get effective permission for the file or folder in C# or C++? Any APIs for that?

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net

My code is working but I need the simplified code and it's not working for the Authenticated Users group. Any other ways to calculate effective permissions?
Is there an API in .NET for getting effective folder permissions for a specific user? I know how get permissions by using `DirectorySecurity.GetAccessRules()`. But in this case I should manually analyze all permissions for user, permissions for groups, that include the user, inherited permissions and user permission for folder.

Is there a function in the Windows API that can return these permissions via platform invoke?

```
namespace DemoProject1
{
     
    class Program
    {
        static Dictionary<String, String> rightsmap = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(IntPtr pDacl, ref TRUSTEE pTrustee, ref ACCESS_MASK pAccessRights);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 4)]
        struct TRUSTEE
        {
            IntPtr pMultipleTrustee; // must be null
            public int MultipleTrusteeOperation;
            public TRUSTEE_FORM TrusteeForm;
            public TRUSTEE_TYPE TrusteeType;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string ptstrName;
        }

        enum TRUSTEE_FORM
        {
            TRUSTEE_IS_SID,
            TRUSTEE_IS_NAME,
            TRUSTEE_BAD_FORM,
            TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_SID,
            TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_NAME
        }
        
        enum TRUSTEE_TYPE
        {
            TRUSTEE_IS_UNKNOWN,
            TRUSTEE_IS_USER,
            TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP,
            TRUSTEE_IS_DOMAIN,
            TRUSTEE_IS_ALIAS,
            TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP,
            TRUSTEE_IS_DELETED,
            TRUSTEE_IS_INVALID,
            TRUSTEE_IS_COMPUTER
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint GetNamedSecurityInfo(
            string pObjectName,
            SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,
            SECURITY_INFORMATION SecurityInfo,
            out IntPtr pSidOwner,
            out IntPtr pSidGroup,
            out IntPtr pDacl,
            out IntPtr pSacl,
            out IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor);

        enum ACCESS_MASK : uint
        {
            FILE_TRAVERSE = 0x20,
            FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x1,
            FILE_READ_DATA = 0x1,
            FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x80,
            FILE_READ_EA = 0x8,
            FILE_ADD_FILE = 0x2,
            FILE_WRITE_DATA = 0x2,
            FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY = 0x4,
            FILE_APPEND_DATA = 0x4,
            FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = 0x100,
            FILE_WRITE_EA=0x10,
            FILE_DELETE_CHILD = 0x40,
            DELETE = 0x10000,
            READ_CONTROL = 0x20000,
            WRITE_DAC = 0x40000,
            WRITE_OWNER = 0x80000,
        
   
            ////////FILE_EXECUTE =0x20,   
        }

        [Flags]
        enum SECURITY_INFORMATION : uint
        {
            OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000001,
            GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000002,
            DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000004,
            SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000008,
            UNPROTECTED_SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x10000000,
            UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x20000000,
            PROTECTED_SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x40000000,
            PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x80000000
        }

        enum SE_OBJECT_TYPE
        {
            SE_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE = 0,
            SE_FILE_OBJECT,
            SE_SERVICE,
            SE_PRINTER,
            SE_REGISTRY_KEY,
            SE_LMSHARE,
            SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
            SE_WINDOW_OBJECT,
            SE_DS_OBJECT,
            SE_DS_OBJECT_ALL,
            SE_PROVIDER_DEFINED_OBJECT,
            SE_WMIGUID_OBJECT,
            SE_REGISTRY_WOW64_32KEY
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          //String UserName = "NT Authority\\Authenticated Users";
            String UserName = "TEST-INC-34\\Test1";
            String Path = "E:\\f1";

            IntPtr pSidOwner, pSidGroup, pDacl, pSacl, pSecurityDescriptor;
            ACCESS_MASK mask = new ACCESS_MASK();
            uint ret = GetNamedSecurityInfo(Path,
                SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
                SECURITY_INFORMATION.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                out pSidOwner, out pSidGroup, out pDacl, out pSacl, out pSecurityDescriptor);

            TRUSTEE t = new TRUSTEE();
            t.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_FORM.TRUSTEE_IS_NAME;
            t.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_TYPE.TRUSTEE_IS_USER;
            t.ptstrName = UserName;
            //Console.WriteLine(t.ptstrName+"  "+ t.TrusteeType);
            ret = GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(pDacl, ref t, ref mask);
            int i = 0;
            List<string> effectivePermissionList = new List<string>();
            string[] rights = new string[14] {"Full Control" ,"Traverse Folder / execute file", "List folder / read data", "Read attributes", "Read extended attributes", "Create files / write files", "Create folders / append data", "Write attributes", "Write extended attributes", "Delete subfolders and files", "Delete", "Read permission", "Change permission", "Take ownership" };
            rightsmap.Add("FILE_TRAVERSE", "Traverse Folder / execute file");
            rightsmap.Add("FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY", "List folder / read data");
            rightsmap.Add("FILE_READ_DATA", "List folder / read data");
            rightsmap.Add("FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES", "Read attributes");
            rightsmap.Add("FILE_READ_EA", "Read extended attributes");
            rightsmap.Add("FILE_ADD_FILE", "Create files / write files");
            rightsmap.Add("FILE_WRITE_DATA", "Create files /  write files");
            rightsmap.Add("FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY", "Create folders / append data");
            rightsmap.Add("FILE_APPEND_DATA", "Create folders / append data");
            rightsmap.Add("FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES", "Write attributes");
            rightsmap.Add("FILE_WRITE_EA", "Write extended attributes");
            rightsmap.Add("FILE_DELETE_CHILD", "Delete subfolders and files");
            rightsmap.Add("DELETE", "Delete");
            rightsmap.Add("READ_CONTROL", "Read permission");
            rightsmap.Add("WRITE_DAC", "Change permission");
            rightsmap.Add("WRITE_OWNER", "Take ownership");
            foreach (ACCESS_MASK item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ACCESS_MASK)))
            { 
                if ((mask & item) == item)
                {
                    effectivePermissionList.Add(rightsmap[item.ToString()]);
                    i++;
                }
               
            }
            //Console.WriteLine(i);
            if (i == 16)
            {
                effectivePermissionList.Insert(0,"Full Control");
            }
            string user = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(Path).GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
            if (user.Equals(UserName))
            {
                if (!effectivePermissionList.Contains("Read permission"))
                {
                    effectivePermissionList.Add("Read permission");
                }
                if (!effectivePermissionList.Contains("Change permission"))
                {
                    effectivePermissionList.Add("Change permission");
                }
                

            }
            foreach (string r in rights)
            {
                if (effectivePermissionList.Contains(r))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(r);
                }
            }
         
           


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a MCVE : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ".NET get effective permissions for user" as a we b search gets lots of interesting hits. You should show in your question what research you have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact answer for my question:

```
namespace EffectiveRightsUsingAuthzAPI
{

    class Program
    {
         

       

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(IntPtr pDacl, ref TRUSTEE pTrustee, ref ACCESS_MASK pAccessRights);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 4)]
        struct TRUSTEE
        {
            IntPtr pMultipleTrustee; // must be null
            public int MultipleTrusteeOperation;
            public TRUSTEE_FORM TrusteeForm;
            public TRUSTEE_TYPE TrusteeType;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string ptstrName;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 4)]
        public struct LUID
        {
            public uint LowPart;
            public int HighPart;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST
        {
            public int DesiredAccess;
            public byte[] PrincipalSelfSid;
            public OBJECT_TYPE_LIST[] ObjectTypeList;
            public int ObjectTypeListLength;
            public IntPtr OptionalArguments;
        };
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct OBJECT_TYPE_LIST
        {
            OBJECT_TYPE_LEVEL Level;
            int Sbz;
            IntPtr ObjectType;
        };
 
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY
        {
            public int ResultListLength;
            public IntPtr GrantedAccessMask;
            public IntPtr SaclEvaluationResults;
            public IntPtr Error;
        };

        public enum OBJECT_TYPE_LEVEL : int
        {
            ACCESS_OBJECT_GUID = 0,
            ACCESS_PROPERTY_SET_GUID = 1,
            ACCESS_PROPERTY_GUID = 2,
            ACCESS_MAX_LEVEL = 4
        };
        enum TRUSTEE_FORM
        {
            TRUSTEE_IS_SID,
            TRUSTEE_IS_NAME,
            TRUSTEE_BAD_FORM,
            TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_SID,
            TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_NAME
        }

        enum AUTHZ_RM_FLAG : uint
        {
            AUTHZ_RM_FLAG_NO_AUDIT = 1,
            AUTHZ_RM_FLAG_INITIALIZE_UNDER_IMPERSONATION = 2,
            AUTHZ_RM_FLAG_NO_CENTRAL_ACCESS_POLICIES = 4,
        }

        enum TRUSTEE_TYPE
        {
            TRUSTEE_IS_UNKNOWN,
            TRUSTEE_IS_USER,
            TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP,
            TRUSTEE_IS_DOMAIN,
            TRUSTEE_IS_ALIAS,
            TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP,
            TRUSTEE_IS_DELETED,
            TRUSTEE_IS_INVALID,
            TRUSTEE_IS_COMPUTER
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint GetNamedSecurityInfo(
            string pObjectName,
            SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,
            SECURITY_INFORMATION SecurityInfo,
            out IntPtr pSidOwner,
            out IntPtr pSidGroup,
            out IntPtr pDacl,
            out IntPtr pSacl,
            out IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor);
        [DllImport("authz.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "AuthzInitializeContextFromSid", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern public bool AuthzInitializeContextFromSid(
                                               int Flags,
                                               IntPtr UserSid ,
                                               IntPtr AuthzResourceManager,
                                               IntPtr pExpirationTime,
                                               LUID Identitifier,
                                               IntPtr DynamicGroupArgs,
                                               out IntPtr pAuthzClientContext
                                               );



        [DllImport("authz.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "AuthzInitializeResourceManager", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern public bool AuthzInitializeResourceManager(
                                        int flags,
                                        IntPtr pfnAccessCheck,
                                        IntPtr pfnComputeDynamicGroups,
                                        IntPtr pfnFreeDynamicGroups,
                                        string name,
                                        out IntPtr rm
                                        );
        [DllImport("authz.dll", EntryPoint = "AuthzAccessCheck", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool AuthzAccessCheck(int flags, 
                                                    IntPtr hAuthzClientContext,
                                                     ref AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST pRequest, 
                                                     IntPtr AuditEvent,
                                                     IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor, 
                                                    byte[] OptionalSecurityDescriptorArray,
                                                    int OptionalSecurityDescriptorCount, 
                                                    ref AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY pReply,
                                                    out IntPtr phAccessCheckResults);

        enum ACCESS_MASK : uint
        {
            FILE_TRAVERSE = 0x20,
            FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x1,
            FILE_READ_DATA = 0x1,
            FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x80,
            FILE_READ_EA = 0x8,
            FILE_ADD_FILE = 0x2,
            FILE_WRITE_DATA = 0x2,
            FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY = 0x4,
            FILE_APPEND_DATA = 0x4,
            FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = 0x100,
            FILE_WRITE_EA = 0x10,
            FILE_DELETE_CHILD = 0x40,
            DELETE = 0x10000,
            READ_CONTROL = 0x20000,
            WRITE_DAC = 0x40000,
            WRITE_OWNER = 0x80000,


            ////////FILE_EXECUTE =0x20,   
        }

        [Flags]
        enum SECURITY_INFORMATION : uint
        {
            OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000001,
            GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000002,
            DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000004,
            SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000008,
            UNPROTECTED_SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x10000000,
            UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x20000000,
            PROTECTED_SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x40000000,
            PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x80000000
        }

        enum SE_OBJECT_TYPE
        {
            SE_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE = 0,
            SE_FILE_OBJECT,
            SE_SERVICE,
            SE_PRINTER,
            SE_REGISTRY_KEY,
            SE_LMSHARE,
            SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
            SE_WINDOW_OBJECT,
            SE_DS_OBJECT,
            SE_DS_OBJECT_ALL,
            SE_PROVIDER_DEFINED_OBJECT,
            SE_WMIGUID_OBJECT,
            SE_REGISTRY_WOW64_32KEY
        }



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //String UserName = "NT Authority\\Authenticated Users";
            do {
                Console.WriteLine("UserName:");
                String UserName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Path:");
                String Path = Console.ReadLine();




                IntPtr pSidOwner, pSidGroup, pDacl, pSacl, pSecurityDescriptor;
                ACCESS_MASK mask = new ACCESS_MASK();
                uint ret = GetNamedSecurityInfo(Path,
                    SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
                    SECURITY_INFORMATION.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | SECURITY_INFORMATION.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | SECURITY_INFORMATION.GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                    out pSidOwner, out pSidGroup, out pDacl, out pSacl, out pSecurityDescriptor);

                IntPtr hManager = IntPtr.Zero;


                bool f = AuthzInitializeResourceManager(1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, null, out hManager);

                NTAccount ac = new NTAccount(UserName);
                SecurityIdentifier sid = (SecurityIdentifier)ac.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
                byte[] bytes = new byte[sid.BinaryLength];
                sid.GetBinaryForm(bytes, 0);
                String _psUserSid = "";
                foreach (byte si in bytes)
                {
                    _psUserSid += si;
                }

                LUID unusedSid = new LUID();
                IntPtr UserSid = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
                Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, UserSid, bytes.Length);
                IntPtr pClientContext = IntPtr.Zero;

                if (f)
                {
                    f = AuthzInitializeContextFromSid(0, UserSid, hManager, IntPtr.Zero, unusedSid, IntPtr.Zero, out pClientContext);


                    AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST request = new AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST();
                    request.DesiredAccess = 0x02000000;
                    request.PrincipalSelfSid = null;
                    request.ObjectTypeList = null;
                    request.ObjectTypeListLength = 0;
                    request.OptionalArguments = IntPtr.Zero;

                    AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY reply = new AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY();
                    reply.GrantedAccessMask = IntPtr.Zero;
                    reply.ResultListLength = 0;
                    reply.SaclEvaluationResults = IntPtr.Zero;
                    IntPtr AccessReply = IntPtr.Zero;
                    reply.Error = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1020);
                    reply.GrantedAccessMask = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(uint));
                    reply.ResultListLength = 1;
                    int i = 0;
                    Dictionary<String, String> rightsmap = new Dictionary<String, String>();
                    List<string> effectivePermissionList = new List<string>();
                    string[] rights = new string[14] { "Full Control", "Traverse Folder / execute file", "List folder / read data", "Read attributes", "Read extended attributes", "Create files / write files", "Create folders / append data", "Write attributes", "Write extended attributes", "Delete subfolders and files", "Delete", "Read permission", "Change permission", "Take ownership" };
                    rightsmap.Add("FILE_TRAVERSE", "Traverse Folder / execute file");
                    rightsmap.Add("FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY", "List folder / read data");
                    rightsmap.Add("FILE_READ_DATA", "List folder / read data");
                    rightsmap.Add("FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES", "Read attributes");
                    rightsmap.Add("FILE_READ_EA", "Read extended attributes");
                    rightsmap.Add("FILE_ADD_FILE", "Create files / write files");
                    rightsmap.Add("FILE_WRITE_DATA", "Create files /  write files");
                    rightsmap.Add("FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY", "Create folders / append data");
                    rightsmap.Add("FILE_APPEND_DATA", "Create folders / append data");
                    rightsmap.Add("FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES", "Write attributes");
                    rightsmap.Add("FILE_WRITE_EA", "Write extended attributes");
                    rightsmap.Add("FILE_DELETE_CHILD", "Delete subfolders and files");
                    rightsmap.Add("DELETE", "Delete");
                    rightsmap.Add("READ_CONTROL", "Read permission");
                    rightsmap.Add("WRITE_DAC", "Change permission");
                    rightsmap.Add("WRITE_OWNER", "Take ownership");


                    f = AuthzAccessCheck(0, pClientContext, ref request, IntPtr.Zero, pSecurityDescriptor, null, 0, ref reply, out AccessReply);
                    if (f)
                    {
                        int granted_access = Marshal.ReadInt32(reply.GrantedAccessMask);

                         mask = (ACCESS_MASK)granted_access;

                        foreach (ACCESS_MASK item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ACCESS_MASK)))
                        {
                            if ((mask & item) == item)
                            {
                                effectivePermissionList.Add(rightsmap[item.ToString()]);
                                i++;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(reply.GrantedAccessMask);




                    if (i == 16)
                    {
                        effectivePermissionList.Insert(0, "Full Control");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(".......................");
                    foreach (string r in rights)
                    {
                        if (effectivePermissionList.Contains(r))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(r);
                        }
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________\n");
            } while (true);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
   
}
```